# To prove a subring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In a commutative ring $R$, if there exists an element $x$ such that $Rx + Rs = R$ for all non-unit elements $s$ outside of the Jacobson radical of $R$, then $x$ is idempotent in $R$ and for each non-unit $s$, having $xR+sR=R$ implies $(1-x)sR=(1-x)R$, and this implies $(1-x)R= F$ is a field. But how can I prove that it is a field?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For any y belongs to (1-x)R is of the form y=(1-x)r, for some r belongs to R, then to prove (1-x)r has an inverse. I couldn't get any hint there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since $x$ is idempotent, then so is $(1-x)$, and this is going to be the identity element of the group $(1-x)R$.
Note also that $(1-x)x=0$.

If $s$ is a unit, then it's already invertible in $R$, so $(1-x)s$ will have inverse $(1-x)s^{-1}$.

If $s$ is not a unit, then by the condition, $xR+sR=R$, we have $(1-x)(xR+sR)=(1-x)R$, where the left side reduces to $(1-x)sR$ because $(1-x)x=0$.
But that implies that there's an $a\in R$ such that $(1-x)sa=(1-x)$, so $(1-x)a$ will be an inverse of $(1-x)s$.

More specifically, apply the condition to decompose $1\in R$ as $xu+sa=1$ with $u,a\in R$, and then multiply by $(1-x)$ to directly obtain $(1-x)sa=(1-x)$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your contribution 